# When a client is evicted from an MQTT broker, will it's LWT be sent?

Tags: mqtt, aws-iot

When a client is connected to the MQTT broker, the broker checks to make sure that the client is still connected.

If the client suddenly disconnects and reconnects relatively quickly, it may connect before the previous client disconnects. The new client connects with the same client ID as the previous client.

When this happens, it is my understanding that the previous client's connection is evicted from the broker. Does this eviction trigger an LWT being sent? If so, is there a way to prevent the LWT for the first client from being sent to any other client subscribed to the topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the LWT is not sent (at least not with mosquitto) and wouldn't be because the keepalive has not expired.

This can be tested easily with `mosquitto` and the `mosquitto_sub`

1. start `mosquitto` on port 1889 with `mosquitto -p 1889`
2. start first `mosquitto_sub` instance with `mosquitto_sub -p 1889 -i foo -v -t '#' --will-topic bar --will-payload "testing"`
3. start second `mosquitto_sub` (to listen for the LWT) with `mosquitto_sub -p 1889 -v -t '#'`
4. start third `mosquitto_sub` with same client id using `mosquitto_sub -p 1889 -i foo -v -t '#'`

You should see the 1st & 3rd clients kicking each other off the broker in the mosquitto log (as written to stdout) and the 2nd shouldn't show any LWT messages being published.